iOS: Using variable fonts in SwiftUI
I am trying to use Variable Fonts in my project. This is a new project that is targeting iOS 18 and I am testing it on simulator. Here is how I am loading and registering a variable font:
public enum VariableFont: String {
    case inter = "Inter"
    case geologica = "Geologica"
}

public enum GeologicaFontAxis: Int {
    case cursive = 258
    case shaerpness = 259
    case slant = 260
    case weight = 257
}

public extension Font {
    
    static func variableFont(
        _ font: VariableFont,
        size: CGFloat,
        axis: [Int: Int]
    ) -> Font {
        Font(UIFont(descriptor: .init(
            fontAttributes: [
                .name: font.rawValue,
                kCTFontVariationAttribute as UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName: axis
            ]
        ), size: size))
    }
    
    static func geologica(size: CGFloat, axis: [GeologicaFontAxis: Int]) -> Font {
        let tuples = axis.map({ (key: GeologicaFontAxis, value: Int) in
            return (key.rawValue, value)
        })
        let axis: [Int: Int] = .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: tuples)
        return variableFont(.geologica, size: size, axis: axis)
    }
    
    static func registerFont(_ fontName: String) {
        guard let fontURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: "ttf") else {
            print("Failed to locate font in bundle")
            return
        }
        guard let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: fontURL as CFURL) else {
            print("Failed to create CGDataProvider from fontURL")
            return
        }
        guard let font = CGFont(fontDataProvider) else {
            print("Failed to create CGFont from data provider")
            return
        }
        if isDebugMode(), let variationAxes = font.variationAxes {
            let axes = variationAxes as NSArray
            for axe in axes {
                dump(axe)
            }
        }
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error) else {
            print("Error registering font: \(String(describing: error?.takeUnretainedValue()))")
            return
        }
        print("Font registered successfully")
    }
}

I have optained Axis information for the font I am using, "Geologia", using fonttools:
<!-- Weight -->
<Axis>
  <AxisTag>wght</AxisTag>
  <Flags>0x0</Flags>
  <MinValue>100.0</MinValue>
  <DefaultValue>100.0</DefaultValue>
  <MaxValue>900.0</MaxValue>
  <AxisNameID>257</AxisNameID>
</Axis>

<!-- Cursive -->
<Axis>
  <AxisTag>CRSV</AxisTag>
  <Flags>0x0</Flags>
  <MinValue>0.0</MinValue>
  <DefaultValue>0.0</DefaultValue>
  <MaxValue>1.0</MaxValue>
  <AxisNameID>258</AxisNameID>
</Axis>

<!-- Sharpness -->
<Axis>
  <AxisTag>SHRP</AxisTag>
  <Flags>0x0</Flags>
  <MinValue>0.0</MinValue>
  <DefaultValue>0.0</DefaultValue>
  <MaxValue>100.0</MaxValue>
  <AxisNameID>259</AxisNameID>
</Axis>

<!-- Slant -->
<Axis>
  <AxisTag>slnt</AxisTag>
  <Flags>0x0</Flags>
  <MinValue>-12.0</MinValue>
  <DefaultValue>0.0</DefaultValue>
  <MaxValue>0.0</MaxValue>
  <AxisNameID>260</AxisNameID>
</Axis>

So this is where the magic numbers in GeologicaFontAxis enum comes from. This looks working and I can see the "Font registered successfully" log and axis data when I run the app:
▿ 4 key/value pairs #0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisName #1
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: Weight #2
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMinValue #3
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 100 #4
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMaxValue #5
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 900 #6
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisDefaultValue #7
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 100 #4
▿ 4 key/value pairs #0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisName #1
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: Cursive #2
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMinValue #3
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #4
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMaxValue #5
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 1 #6
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisDefaultValue #7
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #4
▿ 4 key/value pairs #0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisName #1
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: Sharpness #2
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMinValue #3
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #4
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMaxValue #5
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 100 #6
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisDefaultValue #7
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #4
▿ 4 key/value pairs #0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisName #1
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: Slant #2
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMinValue #3
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: -12 #4
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisMaxValue #5
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #6
      - super: NSNumber
        - super: NSValue
          - super: NSObject
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: kCGFontVariationAxisDefaultValue #7
      - super: __NSCFString
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
    - value: 0 #6
Font registered successfully

The "Geologica" has four axis and logs show this correctly. And here how I use it in SwiftUI:
let titleFont = Font.geologica(
    size: 24,
    axis: [GeologicaFontAxis.weight: 600]
)

Text("modern-airlines", bundle: .module)
    .font(titleFont)
    .textCase(.uppercase)
    .padding(.top, 12)

But it is not working both on simulator or previews. How can I make it work? Can this be a simulator and preview bug?
Resources:

Variable fonts on macOS with SwiftUI
Finding the axes of a variable font


I found the problem: The ID of the axis was wrong. I have tried useing the VFont library:
Text("Title 1")
      .font(.vFont("Geologia", size: 16, axisID: 257, value: 600))

This was also not working but it gave me this error:
This axis with '257' id doesn't exist

I put a dump statement in _setValue funtion of VFont to see what are the IDs available:
▿ 4 key/value pairs
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: 2003265652
    ▿ value: VFont.Axis #0
      - id: 2003265652
      - name: "Weight"
      - minValue: 100.0
      - maxValue: 900.0
      - defaultValue: 100.0
      - value: 100.0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: 1936486004
    ▿ value: VFont.Axis #1
      - id: 1936486004
      - name: "Slant"
      - minValue: -12.0
      - maxValue: 0.0
      - defaultValue: 0.0
      - value: 0.0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: 1129468758
    ▿ value: VFont.Axis #2
      - id: 1129468758
      - name: "Cursive"
      - minValue: 0.0
      - maxValue: 1.0
      - defaultValue: 0.0
      - value: 0.0
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: 1397248592
    ▿ value: VFont.Axis #3
      - id: 1397248592
      - name: "Sharpness"
      - minValue: 0.0
      - maxValue: 100.0
      - defaultValue: 0.0
      - value: 0.0

So I have updated my GeologicaFontAxis enum values with above IDs and it worked:
public enum GeologicaFontAxis: Int {
    case cursive = 1129468758
    case shaerpness = 1397248592
    case slant = 1936486004
    case weight = 2003265652
}

